# I Can't access the getSystrmService function in android.content.context

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I  am trying to access the getSystemService function in xamarin.android but i can't and i  really need an answer should i include or use something before using that function ? i need to use it with wifiManager

Comment: What you have tried ? how ?

Comment: @EmanuelPirovano i tried using this Android.Content.Context but i can't find the getSystrmService function in it

Comment: what you mean ?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can call `WifiManager` as this way:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
```